# Перенос массива JS в массив PHP

Tags: javascript, php, массивы

Есть таблица HTML которую я заношу в массив на JS. Далее необходимо перенести массив из JS в массив PHP для дальнейшей работы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот код заносит данные всей таблицы в массив на JS:

```js
var myArray = new Array();
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('.products__table');
  var tr = table.children().children().not('tr:first-child');
  $(tr).each(function(i) {
    myArray.push($(this).text());
  });
  console.log(myArray);
  $('#send').click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      window.location.href = "admin.php?name=" + myArray[i];
    }
  });
});
```

console.log(myArray) выдаёт всё правильно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```php
$test = $_GET['name'];
echo $testi;
```

Но выдаёт он только последний элемент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: сделайте var_dump

Comment: string(73) "9Арматура 101620Фрунзе. Киргизиятн.56375005412000"

Comment: А что вы ожидаете если у вас открывается урл вида `window.location.href = "admin.php?name=" + myArray[i];`? Естественно что последний открывающийся урл будет содержать последний элемент массива.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо отправить массив на сервер при помощи метода .post() или .get(), или .ajax(). А на серверной стороне получить готовый массив и отработать с ним через цикл. Пример отправки методом .post():

```js
  $('#send').click(function() {
    let url = 'admin.php';
    $.post(url,myArray:myArray,function(date){
        // data - данные с сервера.
    });
  });
```

```php
$myArray = $_POST['myArray'];
```

Comment: не подскажите что писать в //data - данные с сервера.?

Comment: @ШерзодНоров В этой переменной ответ сервера. В вашем примере, мы просим выполниться файл admin.php и результат его работы будет передан в переменную data. Чтобы увидеть то, что в data, значение переменной надо добавить в html. Сделать это можно так: $('body').html(data);.В теге body вы увидите значение(данные) переменной data.

Comment: @ШерзодНоров Мой ответ является решением вашей задачи?

Comment: Не смог сделать как в вашем примере. Но всё-равно спасибо за помощь. Решил проблему по другому. Сделал всё на php. Но это уже в другой теме